# pandas dot product on each sub frame in multi-index data frame

Tags: pandas, matrix, indexing, multiplication

I have the following data `df_matrix`, `level_1` and `level_2` are the multi-index:

```
|level_1|level_2|value_1|value_2|value_3|
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|a      |w      |1      |2      |3      |
|       |y      |4      |5      |6      |
|       |y      |4      |5      |6      |
|       |z      |7      |8      |9      |
|b      |w      |11     |21     |31     |
|       |x      |41     |51     |61     |
|       |y      |41     |51     |61     |
|       |z      |71     |81     |91     |
```

and `df_column`, `id` is the index:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| value_1 | 0.1 |
| value_2 | 0.2 |
| value_3 | 0.3 |

Is there a smart way to do the dot product on every sub-frame without explicitly looping?

I do it like this, but wonder if there is a cuter implicit way, thanks, John

```
import pandas as pd
# set up matrix data
df_matrix = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, 3),
                   (4, 5, 6),
                   (4, 5, 6),
                   (7, 8, 9),
                   (11, 21, 31),
                   (41, 51, 61),
                   (41, 51, 61),
                   (71, 81, 91)],
                  index=[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']],
                  columns=('value_1','value_2','value_3'))

# BTW can I do this rename in constructor?
df_matrix.index.rename(['level_1','level_2'], inplace=True)


# set up column data
df_column = pd.DataFrame([('value_1', 0.1), ('value_2', 0.2), ('value_3',0.3)],
                columns=('level_2', 'factor'))

df_column.set_index('level_2', inplace=True)


# loop each sub frame and do matrix multiplication
df_result = pd.DataFrame()
for l1, new_df in df_matrix.groupby(level=0):
    new_df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True, drop=True)
    df_column.rename(columns={df_column.columns[0] : l1}, inplace=True)
    df_scores = new_df.dot(df_column)
    df_result = pd.concat([df_result, df_scores], axis=1)
    
# result:
df_result.T

#level_2 w    x    y    z
#a       1.4  3.2  3.2  5.0
#b       14.6 32.6 32.6 50.6
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy output is in comments at bottom of my example code

Comment: as a side note, you can pass the levels names to the dataframe with rename_axis. I dont think you can do that via the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the dot function directly; it will be aligned on the common index; after that it is a straightforward unstack, droplevel and rename.

```
(
    df_matrix.dot(df_column)
    .unstack()
    .droplevel(0, axis=1)
    .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)

     w       x       y      z
a   1.4     3.2      3.2    5.0
b   14.6    32.6    32.6    50.6
```

Comment: many thanks - the learning point for me was that `.dot` aligns to common index

Answer (score 2):

Simplier is select `b` for `Series` in `df_column`, then use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df_matrix.dot(df_column['b']).unstack().rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
print (df)
      w     x     y     z
a   1.4   3.2   3.2   5.0
b  14.6  32.6  32.6  50.6
```

Comment: this is not what I am after: You are doing a different matrix multiplication than thye one i want to do. I dont want to create `value_1`, `value_2`, `value_3` columns, I want `w`, `x`, `y`, `z`

Comment: @JohnnieL - I try run your solution and error, for you working?

Comment: apologies I posted an old piece of code: I have updated and also pasted here:

```
df_column = pd.DataFrame([('value_1', 0.1), ('value_2', 0.2), ('value_3',0.3)],
                columns=('level_2', 'factor'))
```

Comment: many thanks - the learning point for me was that `.dot` aligns to common index